# Nothing executes in the main process after the last child process is started, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have this code here:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #iterate over markets_to_track
    for index, market in enumerate(markets_to_track):

        print('connecting to ', market['exmp'])

        #launch a child process for each market
        markets_to_track[index]['multiprocessing_pid'] = Process(target=collect_data, kwargs=market)
        markets_to_track[index]['multiprocessing_pid'].start()

        print('just connected to ', market['exmp'])

     print('main process now does it\'s thing!')
```

The child processes execute fine... There are two `markets_to_track` and they both execute as expected.

The first print that says `"connecting to market['exmp']"` is printed twice.

The second print that says `"just connected to market['exmp']"` is only printed once (after the first iteration of the for loop) and nothing in the main process is executed thereafter.

`print('main process now does it\'s thing!')` never sees the light of day.

What am I missing?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Adding SyntaxVoid's suggestion of flush=True to the print statements has them printing now, but why?!

Comment: Did you get any kind of error messages in your output? Does the program just hang indefinitely or does it stop execution?

Comment: No errors that I can see... both child processes executed for hours last night... I was just going to implement some processing of the data they have been collecting right now in the main thread... and I realized I am stuck. Stopped.

Comment: So just to clarify, the program did terminate but just didn't actually print the final two print statements?

Comment: Where do you run it? Try from terminal if you have not yet. Some IDEs have problems with multiprocessing.

Comment: Can you try adding `flush = True`s to your print statements?

Comment: @RobStreeting no the program never terminates, it is designed to run forever, constantly listening to market data via websocket feeds and reconnecting if they go do. The main process was going to parse all the messages together via shared memory.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid OK we are getting somewhere now... adding flush=True has the last print finally printing!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `flush` to the `print`-statement tells the interpreter to perform the output right now, acquiring the required CPU time ASAP. Otherwise the processing of the stream is scheduled for the moment, when ressources become available. As your sub-processes however constantly allocate CPU-time, the `print`-statement will not be executed until the sub-processes have finished (joined). So the output of the `print` appears at the very end of your program.

The same problem sometimes occur when doing lengthy calculations with status updates, like a progress bar during copying files.